# HTML,CSS, Bootstrap checkbox label should have fixed width regardless of Text

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just need some help and hoping some assistance. I have a bootstrap checkbox button and what it is doing is to change its text when clicked. But I want also to make its width fixed regardless of text because the text is changing when I clicked on the button. I want also to make the text center inside the button. Thank you.

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/koykoys/u3kjbf7j/)

```js
$('#option1').on('click',function(){
 $(this).closest('label').find('span').html('Nice');
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> <span> CLICK ME</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `min-width`. `.btn-group>.btn {min-width: 100px;}`. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u3kjbf7j/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding this bit to your code: You take the clas "btn" and add a fixed width of your liking:

```css
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the final code:

```js
$('#option1').on('click',function(){
 $(this).closest('label').find('span').html('Nice');
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.btn {
width: 200px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> <span> CLICK ME</span>
  </label>
</div>
```